# How to use emmeans function to back transform glm summary

Tags: r, glm, emmeans

I've run an Interrupted Time Series Analysis using a GLM and need to be able to exponentiate outcomes in order to validate. I have been recommended the *emmeans* package, but I'm not quite sure how to do it.

Base R summary is below:

```
summary(fit1a)

Call:
glm(formula = `Subject Total` ~ Quarter + int2 + time_since_intervention2, 
    family = "poisson", data = df)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.4769  -0.5111   0.1240   0.6103   0.9128  

Coefficients:
                         Estimate Std. Error z value            Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)               3.54584    0.09396  37.737 <0.0000000000000002 ***
Quarter                  -0.02348    0.01018  -2.306              0.0211 *  
int2                     -0.23652    0.21356  -1.108              0.2681    
time_since_intervention2 -0.02624    0.04112  -0.638              0.5234    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 63.602  on 23  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 13.368  on 20  degrees of freedom
AIC: 140.54

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

Cant really understand how to get started with *emmeans*. How would I code in order to get the estimate for Quarter, int2 and time_since_intervention2 on the response scale?

Comment: For starters, I wonder if the model is correct. For example, is Quarter numerical, like 1, 2, 3, 4? If so, you need factor(Quarter). Similarly, are int2 and time_since_intervention2 numerical or should one of those be factors too? Finally, should there be interactions among any of these predictors. Did you do residual diagnostics? It is really important to get the model right before proceeding.